# Find opus files on Android

Tags: android, audio-player, android-cursor, opus

Since recently I'm using the OPUS file format in my music library.
Even though Android seems to [support the OPUS file format natively](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats) there are not many music players listing music tracks encoded in this format.

I've wanted to create my own simple music player listing OPUS encoded audio tracks. However I couldn't figure out how to find the files on the system.

The best way would be to use a query/cursor. However OPUS files are just **ignored**:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                           null, null, null, null);

System.out.println(cursor.getCount()); //The size of my music library without .opus files

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
  //.mp3 and .flac files but no .opus files
  System.out.println(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));
}
```

Then I tried to access my music files manually but without success:

```
File musicDirectory = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toURI());
//This directory seems to be empty, length: 0
System.out.println(musicDirectory.list().length);
```

And:

```
File file = new File(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.getPath());
//Exists: false
System.out.println(file.exists());
```

Has anybody got any idea what the problem is, or know any workarounds?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, @Thomas, what did u do to solve the issue? can you update us?

Comment: Hello, @Thomas, what did u do to solve the issue? can you update us?

Comment: @ElioKhattar I actually gave up on this project, because i discovered that the free and open source VLC music player supports OPUS files perfectly. But if I'm not mistaken, they also search for the files manually. If you have the same problem you might want to look at how VLC did it: [vlc-android](https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The best way would be to use a query/cursor. However OPUS files are just ignored

If your Opus files are of a similar vintage as your MP3 and FLAC files (i.e., they have been on your test device for a long time), then `MediaStore` might not know to automatically index them.

> Then I tried to access my music files manually but without success:

There are few problems here:

- The `File` constructor and `toURI()` stuff is pointless, as `getExternalFilesDir()` returns a `File`
- That `File` points to your app-specific portion of [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), so unless your Opus files are there, this `File` will not list them
- If you wanted to switch to the device-level music directory (`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)`), that is not available to you on Android 10 and higher

> And:

A `Uri` is not a file. Calling `getPath()` on a `Uri` whose scheme is anything other than `file` is pointless, and the scheme for `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` is `content`

> know any workarounds?

You could try your `MediaStore` query, but:

- Constrain based on MIME type, and
- Use `MediaStore.Files` instead of `MediaStore.Audio`

That too will not work on Android 10 and higher, but if it worked it would be faster than scanning the music directory tree yourself.

And unless `MediaStore.Audio` starts indexing Opus files, there is no great solution for you on Android 10 and higher. The best would be `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, so the user can point you to a document tree containing Opus files, and you would scan that tree for documents with the Opus MIME type. That might work, but it may also be slow.